# EXPLAIN SELECT.., why TYPE = ALL?

Tags: mysql

Having these 3 tables:

### users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

### posts

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `post_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `author_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
    INDEX `FK_posts__category_id` (`category_id`),
    INDEX `FK_posts__author_id` (`author_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_posts__author_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_posts__category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

### categories

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `category_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And data in tables:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Doe'),
    (2, 'Pen', 'Poe'),
    (3, 'Robert', 'Roe');

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Category 1'),
    (2, 'Category 2'),
    (3, 'Category 3'),
    (4, 'Category 4');

INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `category_id`, `author_id`, `title`, `text`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'title 1', 'text 1'),
    (2, 1, 2, 'title 2', 'text 2');
```

I want to make a simple select (and let MySQL EXPLAIN it):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.post_id, p.title, p.text, c.category_id, c.name, u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM posts AS p
JOIN categories AS c
ON c.category_id = p.category_id
JOIN users AS u
ON u.user_id = p.author_id
WHERE p.category_id = 1
```

I got this:

[image]

What I don't understand is, why has MySQL to do a full table scan at `u` (`users`). I mean there will be only two users it has to retrieve data about (with id `1` and `2`), and these two can be found by primary key `user_id`. Can somebody with more experience help me to understand this? Is there a better way of creating indexes so MySQL don't has to make a full scan on the `users` table to retrieve data about the post authors?

Thanks you!

Comment: How many rows do you have in the tables?

Comment: See 'And data in tables:..' in my question. Only these rows.

Comment: Could somebody explain to my why most people are using such terrible one character aliases when writing queries? What's the reasoning behind this?? Where do they pick this up?

Comment: @PeeHaa This was just an example, but I'm curious what aliases would you use in this case?

Comment: I don't see the reason to use an alias here. And if there would a reason (e.g. trying to join a table multiple times) at least give them sane names. Or are you also only using a single character for your variable names?

Comment: I used these aliases simply because I wanted to write less. I don't believe there is anything wrong with that.

Comment: **ALWAYS** prefer readability and maintainability over lazyness. always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with such a small amount a index search is going to be slower than a sequential search. Thus MySQL is choosing to use a simple table read.

It has to do with operational efficiency here. Lets simply the operations that MySQL has to do to read the entire table vs using a index.

Full read:

1. Open table
2. Read each line one at a time and match criteria
3. Return result set

That is 5 operations.

Index Read

1. Open table
2. For the criteria read the index for each row
3. Using the index pointer locate the row on disk for each row
4. Return resultset

In this case 8 operations.

This is very simplified but unless you have enough data your indexes can slow you down. As the table grows MySQL might choose a different query path. That is why you dont force the use of indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You only have ~3 rows in your `users` table, according to your test data and your EXPLAIN report.

The optimizer can produce skewed results if you have too few rows in the tables.  It may do a table-scan for a tiny table, even if it would use an index for the same query against the same tables with a few hundred or a few thousand rows.

So when doing development, it's important to have a non-trivial amount of test data in your tables if you want to get accurate optimizer reports.

Comment: Beat me to it again Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill. Really useful to know.